# how to intialize array for inner class and assign mulitple values to that class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, inner-class

I have developed vf page which have page block table displaying 3 fields.

I tried to modify it with use of apex :repeat

so that i have created one inner class as

```
public class outer{
    public class filterField {
            public String label {set;get;}
            public String searchFieldName {set;get;}
            public String searchValue {set;get;}
        }
}
```

I want create an array of filterFields.  Populate this with the search field labels and their corresponding search field name, as per the list below.  The searchValue will be initialized to null.

Accname : acc_name
Accname1 : acc_name1
Accname2 : acc_name2
`<apex:repeat>` which repeats for the filterField array

The outputLabel value will be the value of the “label” field of the filterField class; the inputtext value will be the value of the “searchValue” field of the filterField class.

I have tried like :

```
Outerclass.FilterField inc = new Outerclass.FilterField();
FilterField.label = 'ugh';
FilterField.searchFieldName  = 'ram';
FilterField.searchValue  = 'fdg';

FilterField fr=new FilterField{'a','d','s'};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried like public FilterField filter; filter.add('a'); something like that and FilterField filter=new FilterField {'a','aq','as'}; but it showing error @Eric

Comment: Do you know how to declare a List? If not you should head over to trailhead. Filterlist is not a valid type which it why it did not work

Comment: Outerclass.FilterField inc = new Outerclass.FilterField();
       FilterField.label = 'ugh';
       FilterField.searchFieldName  = 'ram';
    FilterField.searchValue  = 'fdg';

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Update your question. Review [ask].

Comment: Sorry instead of FilterField i mention Filterlist

Comment: what does your vf markup look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not too far off, actually. The simple answer to your question is that you initialize a `List` of your inner class the same as you would with any other `List`.

That is, the end result will look similar to this

```
List<Integer> myInts = new List<Integer>{1,2,3};
```

Integers are a bit of a trivial case though. An integer is simply itself, there are no extra fields to be set. Perhaps a better example would be initializing a `List<Account>`...

```
List<Account> myAccounts = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name = Acct1, BillingStreet = '123 b Baker St'),
    new Account(Name = Acct2, BillingStreet = '4 Privet Drive')
};
```

Here we set a few fields on `Account` using the SObject constructor (which allows us to provide name = value pairs). We can't use this exact same pattern in your case (because your inner class is not an SObject), but it'll look similar.

```
// General convention is to have class names start with a capital letter
List<Outer.FilterField> myFilterFields = new List<Outer.FilterField>{
    new Outer.FilterField(),
    new Outer.FilterField(),
    new Outer.FilterField()
};
```

Close, but this doesn't allow you to set class variables like you could with the `Account` example. After initializing your list, you could grab an individual instance from it, and set values like this

```
myFilterFields[0].label = 'abc';
myFilterFields[0].searchFieldName = 'def';
myFilterFields[0].searchValue = 'ghi';
```

But that's rather cumbersome. You can make your life a bit easier by specifying a constructor for the `FilterField` class.

```
public class FilterField {
    public String label {set;get;}
    public String searchFieldName {set;get;}
    public String searchValue {set;get;}

    // public <class name> is the signature for a constructor.
    // You can specify any number of parameters for it
    public FilterField(String label, String searchFieldName, String searchValue){
        // In this case, since our parameter names are the same as our class
        //   property names (also known as variable shadowing), we need to use
        //   this.<class property name> to access the class property
        this.label = label;
        this.searchFieldName = searchFieldName;
        this.searchValue = searchValue;
    }
}
```

Doing that allows you to initialize your list almost the same way as you initialize a `List<Account>`

```
List<Outer.FilterField> myFilterFields = new List<Outer.FilterField>{
    new Outer.FilterField('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
    new Outer.FilterField('123', '456', '789'),
    new Outer.FilterField(null, null, null)
};
```

The difference here is that you can't pass name=value pairs. Your constructor dictates the order that parameters are passed in, so `abc` in the example above will always be placed into the `label` property.